# I am getting babel error while using Yarn workspaces for monorepo

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am new to software field in general and currently I am trying to use monorepo (using yarn workspaces). I have two react applications (bootstrapped with simple webpack and **NOT** create-react-app) called **main** and **product**.

When I go to the **main** package and run "yarn start" it works, similarly when I run the "yarn start" in the **product** package, it works. The problem is when I export the ***Product*** component from the **product** package (to use in main package) and then go to **main** package and run "yarn start" I am getting the following error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpevV.png)

I went through multiple posts here in stackoverflow and online articles but none of them worked for me. Most of them are using create-react-app but I'm using the bare bones.

Since its just an example I've uploaded the code to [github](https://github.com/Pikalo-dragonballz/Monorepo) for reference.

P.S: I have ***.babelrc*** file in both the packages i.e **main** and **product**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.